# Filter Visual Studio 2008's “Members” drop-down list

Tags: visual-studio-2008, filter

Is there a way to modify that list so that it only shows functions instead of all the class variables as well?  Or even just sort by functions first.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say that it is not possible using the IDE as it is.